# Using sed on a compressed file

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have written a file processing program and now it needs to read from a zipped file(.gz unzipped file may get as large as 2TB),

Is there a sed equivalent for zipped files like (zcat/cat) or else what would be the best approach to do the following efficiently

```
    ONE=`zcat filename.gz| sed -n $counts`
```

$counts : counter to read(line by line)

The above method works, but is quite slow for large file as I need to read each line and  perform the matching on certain fields.

Thanks

## EDIT

Though not directly helpful, here are a set of zcommands

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/decompress-and-expand-text-files.html

Comment: Working on a compressed file will be slow anyway.

Comment: My opinion is that unziping a file and reading through a pipe **is** the most efficient way to temporarily open a ziped file and get a result. You don't have to spend time rezipping the file when you're done. It is more likely you can improve the efficiency of your overall operation by being sure your `sed` code is completely optimized OR more likely using one of awk,perl,python to do your calculation. Good luck.

Comment: thanks.. if uncompressed, the file size will cross 2TB.. so its not feasible for my infrastructure..

Comment: 2 TB files!, assuming this is not a one-off, any time you spend figuring this out will pay itself back quickly. Is it possible to break up your files into more managable chunks? If these are log files, see `logrotate` as a method to create date-time-seriesNum stamped filenames. (There are other approaches besides logrotate.) Then you can reduce what you are searching OR at least run parallel processes on multiple files at one time. You'll get better help if you reedit your question as a 2TB processing problem. Good luck!

Comment: >>`i need to read each line and perform the matching on certain fields`  

What exactly is the problem?   I sound sthat you have a higher level logic which is depending on this to be *fast*?  However have you considered that it could be the higher level logic which could be optimized, and you may want to expand the question to include that?

Comment: Is `zgrep "pattern" file.gz` significantly faster than `zcat file.gz | grep "pattern"`?  I haven't measure it, but if it isn't (which I suspect), then some `zsed` command probably wouldn't be any faster than a pipe either.

Comment: `zgrep` is a shell script that does  `zcat file | grep srchtarg`. You should be able to cat zgrep to see what I'm talking about ;-) No speed savings there. 2 TB will always be 200 X longer to process than a 100 MB file, unless you can break up the data into smaller files, and rely on logic, naming conventions, etc to help you search smaller files. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 4):

Well you either can have more speed (i.e. use uncompressed files) or more free space (i.e. use compressed files and the pipe you showed)... sorry. Using compressed files will always have an overhead.

Answer (score 2):

If you understand the internal structure of the compression format it is possible that you could write a pattern matcher that can operate on compressed data without fully decompressing it, but instead by simply determining from the compressed data if the pattern would be present in a given piece of decompressed data.

If the pattern has any complexity at all this sounds like quite a complicated project as you'd have to handle cases where the pattern could be satisfied by the combination of output from two (or more) separate pieces of decompression.